# Dynamic Display of Images from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Redesigning an application from a set number of images stored with other items to display, to a variable number of images stored in a second table.

Found this question and have started modifying from it, but am getting a bit lost: [ASP.Net Display Images in a GridView span across columns and rows? Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732106/asp-net-display-images-in-a-gridview-span-across-columns-and-rows-using-c-sharp?rq=1)

I have the datalist control for asp.net page built, but know the path item will not work:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server"
    RepeatColumns ="2"
    RepeatDirection ="Horizontal"
    RepeatLayout ="Flow">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="ImageQ" runat="server" Width="150px" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ImageFile", "~/photo/{0}") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

But am lost trying to get the data into this list.
Originally The image data was loaded along with other information via the below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(sConstr);

    using (Conn)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("QuestionDetail", Conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));
        command.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
        Conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] imgBytes = (byte[])reader["ImageFile"];
            string encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
            string url = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", encodedBytes);
            Image1.ImageUrl = url;

            byte[] imgBytes2 = (byte[])reader["ImageFile2"];
            string encodedBytes2 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes2);
            string url2 = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", encodedBytes2);
            Image2.ImageUrl = url2;

            byte[] imgBytes3 = (byte[])reader["ImageFile3"];
            string encodedBytes3 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes3);
            string url3 = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", encodedBytes3);
            Image3.ImageUrl = url3;

            byte[] imgBytes4 = (byte[])reader["ImageFile4"];
            string encodedBytes4 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes4);
            string url4 = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", encodedBytes4);
            Image4.ImageUrl = url4;

            txt_QuestionID.Text = reader["Id"].ToString();
            txt_author.Text = reader["Author"].ToString();               
            txt_Date.Text = reader["SubmitDate"].ToString();               
            txt_Stem.Text = reader["Stem"].ToString();

            txt_RespA.Text = reader["RespA"].ToString();
            txt_RespB.Text = reader["RespB"].ToString();
            txt_RespC.Text = reader["RespC"].ToString();
            txt_RespD.Text = reader["RespD"].ToString();
            txt_RespE.Text = reader["RespE"].ToString();

            txt_Answer.Text = reader["Answer"].ToString();
            txt_Critique.Text = reader["Critique"].ToString();
            txt_KeyObjective.Text = reader["KeyObjective"].ToString();

            txt_References.Text = reader["References"].ToString();
            txt_Practice1.Text = reader["PracticeArea1"].ToString();
            txt_Practice2.Text = reader["PracticeArea2"].ToString();
            txt_Practice3.Text = reader["PracticeArea3"].ToString();
            txt_Practice4.Text = reader["PracticeArea4"].ToString();

            txt_IsCloneOf.Text = reader["IsCloneOf"].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

I have taken the Image portions out and am trying to process them to the DataList via a separate code block (and leave the text elements as is) and have a stored procedure that will grab the applicable records.

This section of the pageload is loading placeholders correctly based on the number of images attached to each question,,, but how to get the encoded image read instead of passing a path.....:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (Conn)
                {
                    SqlCommand ad = new SqlCommand("ImageDetail", Conn);
                    ad.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    ad.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt));
                    ad.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
                    SqlDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        if(!Convert.IsDBNull(reader2["ImageFile"]))
                        { 
                        byte[] imgBytes = (byte[])reader2["ImageFile"];
                        string encodedBytes = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
                        string url = string.Concat("data:image/jpg;base64,", encodedBytes);
                        }
                    }
                    reader2.Close();
                    dt.Load(reader2);
                }
                dlImages.DataSource = dt;
                dlImages.DataBind();
```

Still a total noob, and everytime I change controls it takes me awhile to figure out how to use the new one/s. Right now The code will run with no errors,,, but no images either. I had to add the check for "IsDBNULL" as I kept getting this error. I know that the table being accessed by the ImageDetail Stored Procedure has zero null values in any record, and that the stored procedure returns records when fed a QuestionID.

Comment: This is a working answer. So compare your code with that and follow the steps and you should find what you missed over here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694399/2946329

Comment: @S.Akbari One of the issues that I have trouble with is that in both the question you linked to, and the one that I reference in my question is that both are pulling an image address. I have encoded images in the database that have to be retrieved and displayed from the encoded data. I'm lost how to incorporate the reader I use in my original app and incorporate that into the structure of either of the two other posts.

Comment: @S.Akbari Edited question to try and make the issue more clear

Comment: @S.Akbari - Actually it was some posts I found off of Stack Overflow that dealt with the specific issue I had of pulling images that are encoded in SQL rather than linked from a folder structure. As the images we are dealing with are submitted by the public and we have no control over the name we decided to encode the images to that there would be zero chance of you overwriting my "Image1" with your own Image1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to figure this out.

Datalist control:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server"
RepeatColumns ="2"
RepeatDirection ="Vertical"
CellSpacing ="20"
RepeatLayout ="Table">

<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.aspx?id=" + System.Convert.ToString(Eval("ImageID")) %>' /><br />
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageName") %>' Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="1.2em" ForeColor="Navy"/><br />
 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageContent") %>' Font-Italic="true"/><br /> <br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

DataTable definition for populating (note the datasource is previously defined on the page load event):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (Conn)
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from qimages join Images2 on qimages.imageid = images2.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
                    ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = txt_QuestionID.Text;
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                }
                dlImages.DataSource = dt;
                dlImages.DataBind();
```

Finally the code for the "GetImage.aspx" page the retrieves and passes the image to the datalist. This page uses only the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sImageID = Request.QueryString["id"];

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            string sQuery = "SELECT ImageFile from Images2 WHERE ImageID = @ImageID";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(sImageID);

            using (con)
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (DR.Read())
                {
                    byte[] imgData = (byte[])DR["ImageFile"];
                    Response.BinaryWrite(imgData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working to display the database encoded images in two columns based on the question being looked at.

Thanks everyone for the pointers.