# How to Display Images Returned from a Dataset (filled by SQL Query in C# coded DataLayer) on asp.NET webpage?

Tags: c#, image, gridview, dataset, datalist

I am trying to figure out how I can display a series of images returned as a DataSet from an SQL Query in a DataLayer (using 3-Tier architecture in ASP.NET, using C# code behind) so that the images appear as if in a grid or table. I have tried to research similar questions, but I always end up missing some vital piece that would meet my specific intentions. I have tried GridView and can get the images returned to display, but only in a single vertical column – I want these images to display from left to right, and flow through as many rows as necessary to complete the set of images, which GridView seems to be restricted from doing. I came across information regarding DataLists to try to do just that, but cannot seem to get things quite right to make DataList control to actually display anything as yet. I know from my research that with DataList (which I have little actual experience with) the Repeat Horizontally and Repeat Flow attributes can help display the images in the format I am looking for (left to right, top to bottom). Only one column of distinct data is being returned in the dataset (with several rows depending on the SQL query results), and I have a rather specific SQL statement that is essential to this returned dataset, so I need this to stay in-tact.  I have call statements that trickle down to the data layer from the business and presentation layers, so somehow I need to incorporate the initial call statement in the presentation layer into whatever coding is needed to make the dataset returned display the images through the desired control, which seems to lean heavily towards a DataList control.  Most code I find either jumps around to other possible coding, which doesn’t help me, or leaves out some things that may be essential to making things function fully.  So, can anybody provide a more complete coding picture for both the asp.NET/HTML coding and the C# code behind that might get things working?

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and an MS Access Database to test things. My site is also set up using MasterPages if this matters, though the page in question that I am attempting to display images to is not a MasterPage within the website.

Code Samples for what I’ve tried:

GridView attempt:
ASP.NET Page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSwatches" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="SwatchImg" HeaderText="Available Colors">
        </asp:ImageField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        //Initiate Binding of GridView
    //Ensures updated Swatch Data appears in GridView
    BindSwatchesGridView();
}//End Page_Load() Constructor

/*This method calls the data layer to fetch a list of all Distinct Swatches related to the CatalogID 
  then binds the list to the GridView.  It will also store the DataSet in the cache.*/
private ds13thStytchTestDatabase2 BindSwatchesGridView()
{
    /*Establish the path of the Database file 13thStytchTestDatabase2.accdb via server 
        object MapPath() and declare new myDataLayer object*/
    string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/13thStytchTestDatabase2.accdb");
    clsDataLayer myDataLayer = new clsDataLayer(tempPath);

    /*Call BusinessLayer to get list of all relavant Distinct Swatches and set it to variable
        passing CatalogID as a parameter.*/
    ds13thStytchTestDatabase2 swatches = myBusinessLayer.FindSwatches(CatalogID);

    //Fills GridView with data from Database table tblSwatches
    grdSwatches.DataSource = swatches.tblSwatches;

    //Bind Swatch List to GridView then store list in Cache
    grdSwatches.DataBind();
    Cache.Insert("SwatchesDataSet", swatches);

    //Return Completed Apps List Data
    return swatches;
}//End of BindSwatchesGridView() Method
```

Call statement from BindSwatchesGridView to BusinessLayer’s FindSwatches(CatalogID) Method calls a similar Method in the DataLayer where the SQL Statement resides and returns the dataset results up through the BusinessLayer and back to the BindSwatchesGridView Method.  From here the GridView on the ASP.NET webpage is populated as a single verticle column at Page Load as per the BindSwatchesGridView() call in the Page_Load section.

DataList attempt (vers 1):
This attempt, while seeming to be the more versatile solution, is where things have gotten a little muddled…

One potential solution offered to the nearest similar problem I have encountered supplied the following:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" 
              RepeatColumns="5" 
              RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
              RepeatLayout="Flow">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgPrettyPic" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

if (!Page.IsPostBack())
{

    dtImageURLs = GetImageUrlsFromDB();
    dlImages.DataSource = dtImageURLs;

    dlImages.DataBind();
}
```

Along with:

```
protected void dlImages_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

    Image TargetImage = default(Image);
    DataRow DataSourceRow = default(DataRow);

    DataSourceRow = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
    TargetImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgPrettyPicture");

    TargetImage.ImageUrl = DataSourceRow.Item("ImageURL").ToString;
}
```

(Posted by user Dillie-O on Apri 8 ’09 at 22:25) (see [ASP.Net Display Images in a GridView span across columns and rows? Using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732106/asp-net-display-images-in-a-gridview-span-across-columns-and-rows-using-c-sharp) for further reference)

Since I have a 3-tier architecture and a specific SQL Statement already set up in my DataLayer, I altered the above solution offerings to better fit my coding (I thought):

ASP.NET Page:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlSwatches" runat="server"
                RepeatColumns="5"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSwatches" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C# Code Behind (incomplete):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*Call the FindSwatches() method in the BusinessLayer, passing the specified parameter and set this to the 
          DataSet.*/
    ds13thStytchTestDatabase2 dsFindSwatches = myBusinessLayer.FindSwatches(CatalogID);
    dlSwatches.DataSource = dsFindSwatches;
    dlSwatches.DataBind();

}//End Page_Load() Constructor

protected void dlSwatches_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image TargetImage = default(Image);
    DataRow DataSourceRow = default(DataRow);

    DataSourceRow = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;
    TargetImage = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgSwatch");

    TargetImage.ImageUrl = DataSourceRow["ImageUrl"].ToString();
}//End of dlSwatches_ItemsDataBound() Method
```

This method when tried ended up not really being accessed when the webpage was run.  Instead, based on Debugging, there seems to be no direct call to this method tied to the coding suggested for the Page_Load constructor.  So, I made several failed attempts to alter this dlSwatches_ItemDataBound() Method to see if anything else would work.  Nothing has… End result: no images displayed on web page.

DataList attempt (vers 2):
I even attempted to blend the BindSwatchesGridView() into a BindSwatchesDataList() method:

ASP.NET Page (unchanged):

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlSwatches" runat="server"
                RepeatColumns="5"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                RepeatLayout="Flow">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgSwatches" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Initiate Binding of DataList
    //Ensures updated Swatch Data appears in DataList
    BindSwatchesDataList();
}//End Page_Load() Constructor

/*This method calls the data layer to fetch a list of all Distinct Swatches related to the CatalogID 
  then binds the list to the DataList.  It will also store the DataSet in the cache.*/
private ds13thStytchTestDatabase2 BindSwatchesDataList()
{
    /*Establish the path of the Database file 13thStytchTestDatabase2.accdb via server 
        object MapPath() and declare new myDataLayer object.*/
    string tempPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/13thStytchTestDatabase2.accdb");
    clsDataLayer myDataLayer = new clsDataLayer(tempPath);

    /*Call BusinessLayer to get list of all relavant Distinct Swatches and set it to variable
        passing CatalogID as a parameter.*/
    ds13thStytchTestDatabase2 swatches = myBusinessLayer.FindSwatches(CatalogID);

    //Fills DataList with data from Database table tblSwatches
    dlSwatches.DataSource = swatches.tblSwatches;

    //Bind Swatch List to DataList then store list in Cache
    dlSwatches.DataBind();
    Cache.Insert("SwatchesDataSet", swatches);

    //Return Swatch List Data
    return swatches;
}//End of BindSwatchesDataList() Method
```

Again - End results yielded no images being displayed on the web page

Perhaps I am expecting too much from piecemealing solutions I find, trying to fit them into things that already make sense to me (trial and error as it were), and perhaps there is yet a totally different solution that would incorporate the calls to the database through the 3-tier architecture in place instead of gutting it to start something from scratch.  Maybe there’s a completely different way of going about all this.  My experience is limited in alternative methods that would meet my needs so far, so I welcome any suggestions along with some in-depth code to demonstrate the solutions so my understanding may be more complete.  Let me know if there is more information needed for this problem and I’ll try to add it as needed.

Comment: To further clarify the "incomplete" C# Code Behind in the DataList attempt (vers 1), I just meant it's incomplete because the existing code doesn't yield any results., also, the method referred to in the text following that code block is referring to the "protected void dlSwatches_ItemDataBound()" Method in the second part of the code block.

Comment: so what's problem?

Comment: Did I not outline it in enough detail?  I am trying to figure out appropriate coding that will get the images to load in the page in a left-to-right-to-to-bottom format when they are pulled from the database and returned as a DataSet.  Only the GridView works to place images on the page, but not in the format I am looking for.  GridView ONLY displays the images in a single vertical column.  How do I achieve the horizontal format successfully that the DataList information I have come across utilizes so the displayed images are in a RepeatHorizontal RepeatFlow format?